# How can I get the ID for an archive page?

Tags: archives, woocommerce-offtopic

I have woocommerce page for my products that is treated like an archive page. I need to get the ID for the archive page but obviously if I use `$post->ID` or `get_the_id()`, etc. I get the id for the most recent post on that page.

Comment: If *any* of the answer was helpful to you, then consider accepting it. See »[What should I do when someone answers my question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)?« and/or »[Why is voting important](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote)?«, more information about the [wordpress.se] model is available at the [help].

Answer (score 7):

If this is a true page, then you can get the ID of that specific page with `get_queried_object_id()`. This works and will return the ID on the specific pages, single, category, taxonomy, tag and author pages where it is used. True date and time archives and the homepage will **not** have ID's

You can do the following

```
$page_id = get_queried_object_id();
echo $page_id;
```

Just one very important note, `query_posts` breaks the main query which breaks the functionality above. This will lead to incorrect data. So make sure that you never ever use `query_posts`

Comment: When I use that it get an ID of `0` when it should be `6`. I'm not entirely sure how woocommerce loops through the products. However, I know better than to use `query_posts`

Comment: Then your page is not a page but an archive template in which case you will get `0`. If you need to use a page as an archive page, you need to set `has_archive` to `false` when registering the custom post type otherwise your custom page template will never be used and my code will always return `0` as expected. Just remember to flush rewrites after the change

Comment: I had to use a `get_option` provided by woocommerce

Comment: Meaning what exactly?

Comment: The ID is used in a plugin I wrote. Woocommerce stores the ID in an option. I dug deeper into Woocommerce and found it that way.

Comment: Glad you solved the issue. Well, you can post that as an answer and accept it as the correct. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Do you really need to know the ID, for that see @PieterGoosens's answer, or do you just need to know if you are at the post type `product` archive? The latter can easily be achieved by using [`is_post_type_archive()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_post_type_archive):

```
if ( is_post_type_archive( 'product' ) ) {
     // code
}
```

Comment: I use the page id to grab an setting saved via a custom metabox. I found that woocommerce stores that value as an option.